# What does the [1] do when using .where()?

Tags: numpy

I m practicing on a Data Cleaning Kaggle excercise.

In parsing dates example I can´t figure out what the **[1]** does at the end of the indices object.

Thanks..

```
    # Finding indices corresponding to rows in different date format   

    indices = np.where([date_lengths == 24])[1]
    print('Indices with corrupted data:', indices)
    earthquakes.loc[indices]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I can´t figure out what the [1] does at the end of the indices object." Well, did you try *not* using it? What happens when you do that? Do you see how that result relates to the result with the `[1]`? Also, did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: Most python expressions can be understood by evaluating the parts in order of evaluation.  `date_lengths==24`.  The add the `[]`.  Then the `where`.  By this point you should see the need for the `[1]`, which just returns the 2nd item the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation, [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) called with a single argument is equivalent to calling `np.asarray([date_lengths == 24]).nonzero()`.

[`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) return a tuple with as many items as the dimensions of the input array with the indexes of the non-zero values.

```
>>> np.nonzero([1,0,2,0])
(array([0, 2]),)
```

Slicing `[1]` enables to get the second element (i.e. second dimension) but as the input was wrapped into `[…]`, this is equivalent to doing:

```
np.where(date_lengths == 24)[0]
```

```
>>> np.nonzero([1,0,2,0])[0]
array([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an artefact of the extra `[]` around the condition. For example:

```
a = np.arange(10)
```

To find, for example, indices where `a>3` can be done like this:

```
np.where(a > 3)
```

gives as output a tuple with one array

```
(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
```

So the indices can be obtained as

```
indices = np.where(a > 3)[0]
```

In your case, the condition is between `[]`, which is unnecessary, but still works.

```
np.where([a > 3])
```

returns a tuple of which the first is an array of zeros, and the second array is the array of indices you want

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

so the indices are obtained as

```
indices = np.where([a > 3])[1]
```